# How to display a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just want to make this int visible on my page.

I have this function in my script area

```
function showCount()
{
var count = document.getElmentById('friend') 
      count.style.visibility = 'visible'
      count.innerHTML = dDone.toString()
  }
```

at the end of my webpage I have

```
<div id="friend"> 
</div>
```

Also in my body tag I have

```
body onload="showCount()"
```

--

```
var qDone = 0
```

is above the functions.
I don't understand why it is not showing.

Comment: dDone is an int that I do toString() to

Comment: I feel dumb, spelling mistakes....

Comment: There are no `int` types in javascript, just number types that have a value. There is no need to call `toString`, when a number is passed to a method that expects a string, its value is passed as a string. But none of that has anything to do with why the value isn't being displayed. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a spelling mistake:

```
document.getElmentById('friend')
//            ^
//             \__ missing an "e"
```

Look at your JS console and read the error messages. They're helpful.

Comment: How do I access the console?

Comment: @KirsKringle: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`qDone` and `dDone` are (obviously) not the same.

In addition, check spelling on `getElementById`

Finally, you should put a `;` at the end of each line, otherwise you're letting the browser guess and this will end up with inexplicable errors later down the line.

Comment: Thank you, I added the semi-colons as well.  I need to pay better attention.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var count = document.getElementById('friend').innerHTML = qDone.toString();
```